# having difficulties understanding complex swift associatedtype declaration

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

I saw the line of code below at [swift github repository](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/397d801e191a5e75d2ba60c306fbd702af8942fe/stdlib/public/core/RandomAccessCollection.swift)

```
associatedtype Indices : _RandomAccessIndexable, BidirectionalCollection
    = DefaultRandomAccessIndices<Self>
```

I know that an `associatedtype` is an type alias for protocols, and i know how to interpret it in simple cases

But can someone please explain to me the line of code i saw from swift github repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the associated type `Indices` must conform to
`_RandomAccessIndexable` and  `BidirectionalCollection`, and by default is `DefaultRandomAccessIndices<Self>` unless declared (or inferred) otherwise (where `Self` is the actual type adopting the protocol).

Example:

```
struct MyIndex : Comparable {
    var value : Int16

    static func ==(lhs : MyIndex, rhs : MyIndex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
    static func <(lhs : MyIndex, rhs : MyIndex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value
    }
}

struct MyCollectionType : RandomAccessCollection {

    var startIndex : MyIndex { return MyIndex(value: 0) }
    var endIndex : MyIndex { return MyIndex(value: 3) }

    subscript(position : MyIndex) -> String {
        return "I am element #\(position.value)"
    }

    func index(after i: MyIndex) -> MyIndex {
        guard i != endIndex else { fatalError("Cannot increment endIndex") }
        return MyIndex(value: i.value + 1)
    }
    func index(before i: MyIndex) -> MyIndex {
        guard i != startIndex else { fatalError("Cannot decrement startIndex") }
        return MyIndex(value: i.value - 1)
    }
}

let coll = MyCollectionType()
let i = coll.indices
print(type(of: i)) // DefaultRandomAccessIndices<MyCollectionType>
```

`MyCollectionType` is a (minimal?) implementation of a 
`RandomAccessCollection`, using a custom index type `MyIndex`.
It does not define its own `indices` method or `Indices` type,
so that `Indices` becomes the default associated type,
and
[`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/randomaccesscollection/1786098-indices)
 is a default protocol extension method of `RandomAccessCollection`.

Comment: your answer is nothing short of amazing and awesome as always!! Many many many thanks!!